# How to dynamically cut filtered data from two columns and paste them into new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have numerous data structures that take the form of following  table:

```
    traces  length   
0   domain      10
1  length1       1
2  length2       2
3  length3       3
4   width1       4
5   width2       5
6   width3       6
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
    traces  measurments new_traces new_measurements 
0   domain      10    
1  length1       1       width1         4
2  length2       2       width2         5
3  length3       3       width3         6
```

Since my data structures contain various lengths and widths, I can't hard code range information and need something that can sort the traces column regardless of how many lengths and widths there are.  I've been using pandas to try to coax this into shape, but I'm having a lot of issues (because I'm new to this and very naive) and haven't made much progress. Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
df = df.set_index(df['traces'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand = False))
mask = df['traces'].str.contains('width')
df = df.loc[~mask].join(df.loc[mask],rsuffix='_new').rename(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]),axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
s = df['traces'].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].fillna(0).astype(int)
df2 = df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.diff().lt(0).cumsum(),s]))
df = pd.concat([df2.loc[0],df2.loc[1].rename('new_{}'.format,axis=1)],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    traces  length new_traces  new_length
0   domain      10        NaN         NaN
1  length1       1     width1         4.0
2  length2       2     width2         5.0
3  length3       3     width3         6.0
```

Comment: That's not the output I'm getting when I put it into python. The table looks unchanged except there's a NaN where the 0 index was.

Comment: it should work now

Comment: That does work. I applied it to my larger datasets and it works there too. You are incredible. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind accepting one of the answers to close out the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of your original dataframe is `df`, I would first rename the length column and then split the dataframe in two parts, making sure to rename the indices of the second part such that they align with those in the first part the way you want. Then `pd.concat` will do the rest:

```py
df.rename({'length': 'measurements'},
          axis=1, inplace=True)

part_1 = df.loc[:3]
part_2 = df.loc[4:].rename(index=lambda x: x - 3,
                           columns=lambda s: 'new_' + s)

new_df = pd.concat([part_1, part_2], axis=1)
new_df
```

```
    traces  measurements    new_traces  new_measurements
0   domain            10           NaN               NaN
1  length1             1        width1               4.0
2  length2             2        width2               5.0
3  length3             3        width3               6.0
```

Comment: Arne, this solution works for the example, but is there a way to more dynamically accomplish this same task when data structures have different lengths than the example. For instance, I have one table that looks like the one in the example, but also another that has 5 lengths and 5 widths, etc.. I will edit my question to incorporate this aspect. Thank you if you can help!